# dask.dataframe.from_bcolz() starts to process immediately

Tags: dask

I wonder why dd.from_bcolz() starts to do some processing (that grows alot when N columns goes up and there are string type columns) immediately when called.

And dd.read_hdf() doesn't do much processing when called, but only when dask.dataframe is used - then read_hdf() reads and process HDF5 chunk by chunk...

I like how read_hdf works now, the only problem that hdf5 table cannot have more then ~1200 columns, and dataframe does not support columns of arrays. And hdf5 format is not column based after all...

```
In [1]: import dask.dataframe as dd

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: import bcolz, random

In [4]: import numpy as np

In [5]: N = int(1e7)

In [6]: int_col = np.linspace(0, 1, N)

In [7]: ct_disk = bcolz.fromiter(((i,i) for i in range(N)), dtype="i8,i8",\
   ...:                          count=N, rootdir=r'/mnt/nfs/ct_.bcolz')

In [8]: for i in range(10): ct_disk.addcol(int_col)

In [9]: import dask.dataframe as dd

In [10]: %time dd.from_bcolz(r'/mnt/nfs/ct_.bcolz', chunksize=1000000, lock=False)
CPU times: user 8 ms, sys: 16 ms, total: 24 ms
Wall time: 32.6 ms
Out[10]: dd.DataFrame<from_bc..., npartitions=10, divisions=(0, 1000000, 2000000, ..., 9000000, 9999999)>

In [11]: str_col= [''.join(random.choice('ABCD1234') for _ in range(5)) for i in range(int(N/10))]*10

In [12]: ct_disk.addcol(str_col, dtype='S5')

In [13]: %time dd.from_bcolz(r'/mnt/nfs/ct_.bcolz', chunksize=1000000, lock=False)
CPU times: user 2.36 s, sys: 56 ms, total: 2.42 s
Wall time: 2.44 s
Out[13]: dd.DataFrame<from_bc..., npartitions=10, divisions=(0, 1000000, 2000000, ..., 9000000, 9999999)>

In [14]: for i in range(10): ct_disk.addcol(str_col, dtype='S5')

In [15]: %time dd.from_bcolz(r'/mnt/nfs/ct_.bcolz', chunksize=1000000, lock=False)
CPU times: user 25.3 s, sys: 511 ms, total: 25.8 s
Wall time: 25.9 s
Out[15]: dd.DataFrame<from_bc..., npartitions=10, divisions=(0, 1000000, 2000000, ..., 9000000, 9999999)>
```

And it's getting even worse when N (nrows) grows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like as written today `from_bcolz` automatically categorizes object dtype columns.  So it's doing a full read of all object dtype columns and calling `unique` on them.  You can turn this off by setting `categorize=False`.

Please raise a github issue if you think that this behavior should be changed.